# Can I use "parse" and "parsing" as nouns?

Tags: word-usage, parsing

Can I use the word "parse" (any type of analysis in linguistics) as a noun?

For example:
a morphological parse
a phonetic parse
a sentence parse
a word parse
a text parse

**(1)** *We need to do the morphological **parse** of this word*.
**(2)** *We need to do the morphological **parsing** of this word*.

**(3)** *We need to do the morphological and phonetic **parses** of this word*.
**(4)** *We need to do the morphological and phonetic **parsings** of this word*.

Could you tell me please which of (1), (2), (3) & (4) are correct and which are not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they're correct, but not natural because it's simpler to use "parse" as a verb in all those sentences:

> We need to **parse** the morphology and phonology of this word

or even better:

> We need to parse this word morphologically and phonologically.

Answer (score 0):

Merriam Webster says [parse](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parse) can be a noun.

The variations of qualifier of the parse type will not change the result.

I find all of your examples acceptable.

Comment: Sorry, to understand how to treat your answer, it's important to know: are you a native English speaker? (I couldn't find this information in your profile.) Thanks.